# Quick fermentaion, what should i do?

Tags: fermentation, temperature, fermentation-temperature, secondary-fermentation

I made a batch of cider 6 days ago, and it started fermenting nicely, however now the bubbles in the air lock have slowed to nearly 1/min (according to my recipe means it's fermented)
However this is really quick! it's pretty hot here (we've had a few 35 degree C days)
Will it be alright? should i rack it?
also, should i go about a secondard fermentaion?
cheers

Answer (score 2):

A hot ferment is likely to generate some unwanted higher order alcohols that taste like solvent.  You must taste it first to really know where you stand.
Some may say you can "age that stuff out" and its worth a try.  But while its aging think about how better to control your process and you'll be drinking the next batch before this batch ever ages out.

Answer (score 0):

You should measure the gravity to determine if fermentation is complete.  Airlock activity is an inaccurate indicator.  Your recipe should list an expected final gravity, for a cider I'd expect it to be around 1.000 or below.

High temperatures will cause fermentation to complete faster, and as brewchez mentioned, you will get better results if you can do a colder, slower fermentation.

Racking to a secondary may help clarify the cider, but isn't necessary, nor will it do anything to help a high temperature fermentation.

Answer (score 0):

Cider is more like wine than beer.  I give my ciders a good month or so in primary and several months in secondary.